# Which countries allow express entry immigration like Canada

Tags: working-visas, work-permit

I'm trying to immigrate out my country after I complete my course this year. Please could you suggest if any country apart from Canada has an immigration pool system? I'm hoping to graduate and apply for a pool system where I'm selected by employers within the visa application system, instead of looking for an employer online on job boards which is quite tiresome to apply.
I've been applying to at least 10+ employers each month since January 2021, and still haven't found any sponsor for my work permit.

A simple list of countries that allow express-entry-system in their immigration plan.
Thanks.

Comment: Few candidates are actually passively selected by employers from the pool. Proactive engagement with potential employers is still the norm.

Comment: Ok. Any other country allowing a pool system? How do people find and employer in the USA? They have a petition system. Does that require an employer sponsorship?

Comment: @mk117 each country has its own rules. I'm not familiar with the "pool system" you're referring to, but generally being sponsored by an employer requires at least some active job search. If you're not a world-famous genius and a star in your field, why would employers go through the trouble of getting you through the immigration system if you're not even trying to apply for a job?